# Visualize a sparse matrix using Python Turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparse-matrix, turtle-graphics

I'm stuck on this problem.

```
def showMatrix(turtle_object, sparse_matrix):
```

The `showMatrix()` function will visualize the matrix contents using a grid of dots. Each grid location will correspond to a single matrix location (row, column). The presence of a "dot" indicates a non-zero entry.

First, you need to set the display coordinates to match the matrix extent using the
`screen.setworldcoordinates()` method. In other words, the lower left corner of the display will
become coordinate (0,0) and the upper right corner will be (rows-1, columns-1). Changing the screen
coordinates in this way simplifies the mapping of matrix indices to screen coordinates by matching the "grid"
and matrix coordinates.

Using the turtle `.goto` and `.dot` methods, plot a red dot for each matrix.

This is the work I've done so far:

```
def matrix(n, init):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            row.append(init)
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix



def sparse_matrix(matrix,n,value):
    import random
    ctr = 0
    while ctr < n:
        row = random.randint(0,order(m)-1)
        col = random.randint(0,order(m)-1)
        if matrix[row][col] != value:
            matrix[row][col] = value
            ctr += 1
    return matrix

def showMatrix(turtle_object, sparse_matrix):
    for i in len(m):
        for j in len(m):
            if sparse_matrix[i][j] != 0:
                sparse_matrix[i][j] = turtle_object
    return sparse_matrix
```

Comment: A couple of pieces of information are needed to address this question. The first is what is the format of `sparse_matrix`?   The second is what code have you written so far to solve this?

Comment: edited it in above

Comment: What question are you trying to ask us?

Comment: How do I show the sparse matrix on turtle? I'm not sure how to use screen.setworldcoordinates(). What does the problem mean by (rows-1, columns-1)?

Answer (score 3):

> What does the problem mean by (rows-1, columns-1)?

This is tied up with your mysterious `m` variable and the `order()` function you left undefined.  Let's proceed anyway.  We can see from the `matrix()` function we're dealing with a square matrix but let's not even assume that.  Within the `sparse_matrix()` function, we can figure out rows and columns by doing:

```
rows = len(sparse_matrix)
columns = len(sparse_matrix[0])
```

Along with checking that `rows` isn't zero.

> How do I show the sparse matrix on turtle?

Your `sparse_matrix()` function isn't using `turtle_object` appropriately -- we don't want to store it, we want to ask it to draw things.  And this function probably shouldn't return anything.  I'm guessing it should look something like:

```
def showMatrix(turtle_object, sparse_matrix):
    rows = len(sparse_matrix)

    if rows == 0:
        return

    columns = len(sparse_matrix[0])

    turtle_object.penup()

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(columns):
            if sparse_matrix[r][c] != 0:
                turtle_object.goto(c, r)
                turtle_object.dot(dot_size, "red")
```

Where `dot_size` is 1 for now.  Wrapping this in some turtle code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# ...

m = 6

screen = Screen()

dot_size = 1

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

mat = matrix(order(m), 0)
sparse_matrix(mat, order(m / 2), 1)

showMatrix(yertle, mat)

screen.mainloop()
```

We get an unsatisfactory graph:

[image]

As everything is too small and needs to be scaled up.

> I'm not sure how to use screen.setworldcoordinates()

Rather than add a scaling factor directly to our graphing code, we can use turtle's own `setworldcoordinates()` to bend the window to our graph limits:

```
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, order(m), order(m))

dot_size = screen.window_width() / order(m)
```

This gives us something a little more visually satisfying:

[image]

I hope this rough sketch gets you moving in the right direction.

Comment: It's still not displaying anything. Where did order(m) come from?

Comment: @BrowserM, `order(m)` came from the code you supplied: `row = random.randint(0,order(m)-1)`

Comment: right. okay but i tried your code but it isn't displaying the matrix in turtle graphics

Comment: here's the order function i left out def order(matrix):
    return len(matrix)